# Create command with Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I am trying to look for solutions to create a command to insert into the database for data dynamically
I have not found any solutions 
can you help me by sites 

I already create a command by consulting the official documentation of Symfony
but my prblème is how to create a command to supply a database that use DoctrineFixturesBundle

```
<?php
namespace  Test\FrontBundle\Command;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\Question;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DialogHelper;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ConfirmationQuestion;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException;
class HelloCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
protected function configure()
{
    $this
        ->setName('demo:alimentation')
        ->setDescription('Alimentation base de données ')
        ->setDefinition(array(
           new InputOption('table', '', InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'Le nom de la table '),
           new InputOption('entity', '', InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'entity concerned')
        ))

      ;
}

protected function interact(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    parent::interact($input, $output);
    //$dialog = $this->getDialogHelper ();
    $helper = $this->getHelper('question');
    $question = new ConfirmationQuestion('Continue with this action?', false);

    if (!$helper->ask($input, $output, $question)) {
        return;
    }
    $output->writeln(array(
        '',
        '      Bienvenue    ',
        '',
        'Cet outil va vous permettre de insérer dans la base de donnée dynamiquement ',
        '',
    ));

    $dialog = $this->getHelperSet()->get('dialog');
    $entity = $dialog->ask($output, 'What is the name of the entity?');
    $input->getOption('entity');
    $table = $dialog->ask($output, 'What is the name of the table?');
    $input->getOption('table');
    $input->setOption('entity', $entity);
    $input->setOption('table', $table);

}

protected function getDialogHelper()
{
    $dialog = $this->getHelperSet()->get('dialog');
    if (!$dialog || get_class($dialog) !== 'Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\Helper\DialogHelper') {
        $this->getHelperSet()->set($dialog = new DialogHelper());
    }

    return $dialog;
}
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $dialog = $this->getDialogHelper();
    if ($input->isInteractive()) {
        $question = new ConfirmationQuestion('Do you confirm generation?', true);
        if (!$dialog->askConfirmation($output, $question->getQuestion(), true)) {
            $output->writeln('<error>Command aborted</error>');

            return 1;
        }
    }
    // On recupere les options
    $entity = $input->getOption('entity').'()';
    $table = $input->getOption('table');
    $name = $input->getArgument('name');
    $prenom = $input->getArgument('prenom');





public function createAction(Request $request)
{
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(new $entity)//un passage d'identité
        ->add('name', null, array('label' => 'Nom de l\'album '))
        ->add('type', null, array('label' => 'Type de l\'album'))
        ->add('artist', null, array('label' => 'Artist'))
        ->add('duration', null, array('label' => 'Duration de l\'album'))
        ->add('released', 'date', array('label' => 'Date de l\'album'))
        ->add('submit', 'submit')// les add pour la personalisation
        ->getForm();//pour récupérer le formulaire
    //c'est la logique :il faut le déplacer

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($request->isMethod('post') && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($form->getData());
        $em->flush();
        return $output->$this->render('TestFrontBundle:Sheet:create.html.twig', array('form' => $form->getForm()->createView()));

    }
}


}
```

Comment: You have to develop it following the Symfony documentation and if you will encounter an issue post it here adding the code used.

Comment: I already create a command by consulting the official documentation of Symfony
but my prblème is how to create a command to supply a database without using DoctrineFixturesBundle

Comment: Maybe update your question with some code.  To insert you just pull the entity manager from the container, new your entity then do persist/flush,

Comment: What do you mean by "to supply a database"? Also, please add your command code to the question. It will help us to provide better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The command is just replacing your controller, you can still use services inside it

```
class YourCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName( 'your:command' );
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $container = $this->getContainer();
        $service = $container->get( 'your.service' );
        $service->insertYourDataDynamicaly($paramsYouNeed)
```

Comment: @ Tomáš Votruba
i  want to insert into Data base with a command

Comment: @Khouloud - Are you expecting the command to somehow pop up a form?  Cause that is not going to happen.